# If a GDP deflator is continually greater than 100%, does that mean inflation is still occuring?

Tags: gdp, inflation

If a GDP deflator is continually greater than 100%, does that mean inflation is still occuring?

If the difference in deflators from year to year is continually greater than 1%, does that mean inflation is occuring at a greater and greater rate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a deflator greater than 100 means that the price level is higher than in the base year. It doesn't mean that inflation is still occurring. In fact, you could be **experiencing deflation** after a period of inflation and if prices today are still higher than the base year, have the deflator be above 100. A growing deflator is an indication of inflation. To detect inflation acceleration you'd need to see changes in the log(deflator) growing over time.